# What does the global keyword do if it is not used in the scope of a function?

Tags: php, web

What does the `global` keyword do if it is not used in the scope of a function (file is not included from inside a function)

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$a=1;
global $a;
echo $a;
?>
```

1. Using global keyword outside a function is not an error. [Tick]
2. It can be used if the file is included from inside a function. [Tick]
3. But what does the global keyword do when it is used in a "global file" (file that is not included from inside a function) ?

Comment: global === evil. Keep away from the dark side...

Comment: All it does is ensure that the variable is really from the global scope. It is a no-operation if already in global scope.

Comment: @mario finally someone who understands what I'm trying to say. you may wanna post that as answer thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php :

> Using global keyword outside a function is not an error. It can be used if the file is included from inside a function.

Comment: I mean I know using global keyword outside a function is not an error. I know it can be used if the file is included from inside a function. But what does the global keyword do if it is not used in the scope of a function?

Comment: It's like you've declared it outside the scope of a function without the global keyword, but with the difference that the last one won't be global if the file is included inside another function. If that's not the case, it's the same.
If that's not the answer you're looking for, please explain yourself better, because I could be misunderstanding...